# Difficulty debugging WCF Service in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, azure

I think I'm having an issue where, if I set breakpoints in a ASP Azure project, the page just freezes without letting me step around in Visual Studio 2010. I'm not sure if I have a bug, or if I'm doing something wrong.

I have a Silverlight 4 app that consumes a WCF service made available from an Azure project. If I start up VS, build, and run, everything works fine. If I set a breakpoint in the service `getData()` method, the browser tab becomes unresponsive. If I unset the breakpoint, it remains unresponsive until I restart visual studio.

I have the Azure project set as my web role. I am able to hit breakpoints in WebRole.cs in the ASP project, but it seems like putting a breakpoint in the .svc file messes it up.

Is this a known issue? Or could I be doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't how the Azure project might effect things but but you might want to look at:

[Configuring Message Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx)

[Service Trace Viewer Tool (SvcTraceViewer.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx)

[WCF Test Client (WcfTestClient.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx)